# System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Text property has already been set and can only be set once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a simple validation for a `textBox`however I'm geting the fallowing error in my XAML.

> System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Text property has already been set and
>   can only be set once.

As you can see from my code I don't havn't set the property twice. Not sure why this is happening.

My code is as fallows

```
    <TextBox x:Name="tbxName" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Width="120" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationErrorTemplate}">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:NameValidator></local:NameValidator>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Yes it does I just assumed it wouldn't. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Happening to me in VS2022 and .NET 7. I'm using `<TextBox.Text>Some multiline text</TextBox.Text>` syntax to inject multi-paragraph text in my TextBox using WPF Designer. The project runs fine though.